# QGIS labeling: expression that shows values from one attribute except when the objects has a value x at another attribute

Tags: qgis-3, labeling

I want to label each object of my layer with the values of a certain attriubte. However, if an object has the value "1" at another attribute, this label should be invisible or not rendered.

Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if(attribute_2=1,'',attribute_1)`

Set this as the expression you label your objects by (and change the column names accordingly). If your conditional attribute (#2 here) equals 1, then there will be an empty label, otherwise the feature will be labelled with attribute #1.

You could also use this expression to manage transparency or similar, but this should be the easiest solution.

I don't know how this behaves if your labels have a background.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rule based labeling`, add a rule (the `+` icon at the bottom)

The condition should use the other field (ex: `a <> 1`) and when the filter matches, label the feature with the primary field (ex: `b`)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Or, you can go in the rendering tab and set an expression in the *Show label* parameter like :

```
"other_attribute" != 'the value you don't want'
```